# How to display <div>s iterated with ngFor one by one with button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to do something like a questionnaire. I am fetching out the questions from a database and iterating them in my template using ngFor and ngIf and they are working fine. My problem is that i will like to display the questions one by one on the screen for the user to answer and then click next to go to the next question but I am not sure how to go about this.

[This is the image of what i have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ3hY.png)

my template:

```
<div *ngFor='let quest of questions; let i = index'>
    <div *ngIf="i">
        <ul>
            <li>{{quest.question}}</li>
            <li>{{quest.a}}</li>
            <li>{{quest.b}}</li>
            <li>{{quest.c}}</li>
            <li>{{quest.d}}</li>
            <li>{{quest.e}}</li>
            <button>Next</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

question is being fetched from a database as an associative array.

How do i add a click event that will display the divs one by one according to the index number. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a stepper like https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview?

Comment: @PaRi It looks cool but can data be iterated through it with ngFor directive?

Comment: Hi. When you click on next, do you need to see the questions you've passed or just the current one?

Comment: Just d current one. The user will be told if he is right or wrong immediately

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do could be achieved using two arrays. Let they be `array1` and `array2`. Now `array1` would have all those questions which you had fetched from the database and `array2`, initially, would only have one question copied from `array1`. On clicking the `Next` button, after validating if the answer was correct or not, you just copy the next question from `array1` to `array2`.

Inside your template file, you'd now use `ngFor` on `array2`.

Edit:
If you want to show only one question then you don't have to maintain second array (`array2`). Initialize a variable and store the value at last index of `array1`.
Now after every `Next` click, you just have to update that variable. Note that, in this case you might need to keep track of a index which you want to copy next in a separate variable.
Also in your template fike, you don't have to use ngFor.

Comment: Thanks @riazosama but how do copy a question from array1 to array2  and dynamically increment the index?

Comment: `array2[index + 1] = array1[array1.length - array2.length]`. Pass the index from Template file to the ts inside ngFor. You have to do something like this. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It is almost working but then the previous questions are still displayed on the screen. How to make the previous questions to go away and just the current question to be displayed. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Your question doesn't state that requirement. Anyways, I've update my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You try this.

```
   <div *ngFor='let quest of questions.slice(0, index)'>
        <ul>
           <li>{{quest.question}}</li>
           <li>{{quest.a}}</li>
           <li>{{quest.b}}</li>
           <li>{{quest.c}}</li>
           <li>{{quest.d}}</li>
           <li>{{quest.e}}</li>
           <button (click)="next()">Next</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And your component

```
private index: number = 1;
next() {
    if (questions.length >= index) {
        index++;
    }
}
```